# What's wrong with save svg to png script?

Tags: javascript, svg, save

I got a script for save svg to png. I got this script from here: [svg to png](http://techslides.com/save-svg-as-an-image)
Thanks for the guy.

I tried to paste this t my code to use for save the generated grid to png. But it doesn't works.

Here's the part of the html:

```
<div class="span6" style="text-align:center">
   <div id="container"></div>
   <!--These are for save SVG-->
   <button id="save">Save as Image</button>
   <div id="svgdataurl"></div>
   <div id="pngdataurl"></div>
   <canvas width="960" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here's the part of the javascript:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        d3.select("#save").on("click", function(){
            var html = d3.select("svg")
                .attr("version", 1.1)
                .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
                .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

            console.log(html);
            var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
            var img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'">'; 
            d3.select("#svgdataurl").html(img);

            var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
                context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var image = new Image;
            image.src = imgsrc;
            image.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

                //save and serve it as an actual filename
                binaryblob();

                var a = document.createElement("a");
                    a.download = "sample.png";
                    a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                var pngimg = '<img src="'+a.href+'">'; 
                    d3.select("#pngdataurl").html(pngimg);

                a.click();
            };

        });

        function binaryblob(){
            var byteString = atob(document.querySelector("canvas").toDataURL().replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));
            var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
            var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
                ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
            }   
            var dataView = new DataView(ab);
            var blob = new Blob([dataView], {type: "image/png"});
            var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
            var newurl = DOMURL.createObjectURL(blob);

            var img = '<img src="'+newurl+'">'; 
            d3.select("#img").html(img);
        }

    </script>
```

But I paste the whole code in jasfiddle as well:

[jsfiddle test](https://jsfiddle.net/bwubLuLn/2/)

Comment: In your fiddle, it is related to a mixed content error. Load: https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js instead of http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js. See https://jsfiddle.net/bwubLuLn/3/

Comment: Unfortunately I got a black image instead of mine.